# What is the probability of *not* rolling a $5$ or a $6$ in the first $2$ rolls

Tags: probability

This may be an elementary seeming question but I can't quite figure out how to calculate the probability of losing. I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the probability I won't roll a $6$ and a $5$ with 5 dice in two rolls.

What I know: There are $7,776$ $\cdot (6^5)$ possible outcomes total. I can win if I roll a $6, 5, 3, 2, 1$ or $5, 4, 3, 6, 2$. Basically $6, 5, x, x, x.$ (Here,$x$ is any number). Any number in any combination as long as there is a $6$, a $5$ or both.

But I want to find the losing combinations since that is much easier than counting up the winning combinations. All of the losing combinations will not have a $6$ or a $5$.

Comment: So ... you win if you have a 6, a 5 or both ... but that's not the same as 6,5,x,x,x.  I am confused ... Do you need one of those or both?  You later say that the losing combinations do not have a 6 or 5 ... that's compatible with a winning (assuming winning is the same as not losing) combination having a 6 or a 5 ... but again that is not the same as 6,5,x,x,x

Comment: It's a little unclear whether a winning roll requires a $6$ or a $5$, or a $6$ and a $5$.  It mostly sounds like the former, but the end of your first paragraph sounds like it's the latter.

Comment: To not roll a 6 or a 5 on 5 dice = $(\frac 46)^5$

Comment: Whoops, sorry. You can win as long as there is a 6, a 5, or a 6 and a 5. So, to calculate the losing probability I would have to make sure there are no 6's or 5's.

Comment: Is this the game? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship,_captain,_and_crew  If so, the probability of losing in this game is not the same as the probability of not rolling a 5 or 6 with 5 dice in two rolls. So: should you maybe change the title to reflect your real question?

Comment: @ka5 OK, so it's not throwing a 5 or 6 with any of the dice. so that's $(\frac{4}{6})^5=(\frac{2}{3})^5$ as already pointed out.

Comment: @ka5 Saw your edit .. thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the event that the first roll of five dice includes at least one 6.
Let $B$ be the event that the first roll of five dice includes at least one 5.

What you want (eventually) is to find the value of $P(A\cap B),$
but you are thinking of doing this by computing 
$1-P(A\cap B) = P(A^\complement \cup B^\complement)$ first.

In turn, this seems easiest to compute as follows:
\begin{align}
P(A^\complement) = P(B^\complement) &= \left(\frac56\right)^5,\\
P(A^\complement \cap B^\complement) &= \left(\frac46\right)^5,\\
P(A^\complement \cup B^\complement) &= 
P(A^\complement) + P(B^\complement) - P(A^\complement \cap B^\complement) \\
&= 2 \left(\frac56\right)^5 - \left(\frac46\right)^5.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Thank you for all the other answers as well.